# sip making a call - 401 Unauthorized

Tags: sip, asterisk

I am working on a SIP client. I'm monitoring with Wireshark the SIP packets.

Register with the SIP server works fine.

When making a call, I have this:

```
Client - INVITE message
Server - 401 UNAUTHORIZED
Client - INVITE message
Server - 403 Forbidden
```

I do not have access to the server. What could go wrong? Why can't I make a call?

What is with that 401 and then 403 if registering worked ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is noramal. Server ask for authorization(401). After that it say authorization incorrect.

That is normal behavour for any of this:

1) You use incorrect secret for this username

2) You use domain name/realm which is incorrect and domain name/realm is set on server.

If registration work ok, can be

1) Server work with registration different way - contact server support

2) You dialling in incorrect format or this number not allowed to call with your extension.

Comment: It is not a problem. It is incorrect setup or really FORBIDDEN on server side. You should contact support.

Comment: this seems to work for me if I change certain codecs that are selected. I am using linphone as my sip client. why could it be happening like this?

Answer (score -1):

Another reason for that error: device trying to register is not sending authentication.

while the server may request authentication

Answer (score -1):

It is an old thread but maybe it helps someone: sip server can be in a night/holiday mode which may require different access levels for clients.

Answer (score -1):

you need to send to telco your sip credentials...need to changed your sip credentials parameter..to make you authorized for outgoing call